# Adding com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0 to my dependencies gives me an error

Tags: android

When a try to add  "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'" I get an error:All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification. I have read a lot of similar questions, but they don't help me at all. 
     Teacher told us to add banners to our apps, but after finishing learning java, we had only 3 lessons on android, so i cant understand dependencies and so i cant solve this problem. This is my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kydja.ignatius.funfacts2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

You can add noInspection to do not verify version

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

Or you can change sdk and libraries to 26 version

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.andrei.texteditor2"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

Comment: Is this because "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0" depends on appcompat version 26, but not version 27?